# Form submission not showing up in Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an HTML form and trying to store the results in firebase. Here is a picture of my Firebase layout:[image]

However, when I submit the form, the entries do not go into Firebase, and I'm not sure why. Here is my HTML code in `index.html`:

```
<section id="input" class="section-padding wow fadeInUp delay-05s">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="service-title pad-bt15">Add a Marker</h2>
            <p class="sub-title pad-bt15">If you are in need of assistance, fill out the details below, and a marker will be<br>placed on the map for others to view and respond to.</p>
            <hr class="bottom-line">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-form">
        <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
        <div id="errormessage"></div>
        <form id="markerForm" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name"  /> 
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" />
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address"  />
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
            <center><button id="formbutton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit">SUBMIT</button></center>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Note that in the `<head>` tag in the HTML file, I am calling this:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

And at the very beginning of `<body>`, I call this:

```
 <script src="index.js"></script>
```

And here is my JS code in index.js:

```
var config = {
    // my config details
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("markers");

  var submit = function () {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var address = $("#address").val();
    var subject = $("#subject").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    ref.push({
      "name": name,
      "email": email,
      "address": address,
      "subject": subject,
      "message": message
    });
  };

  $(window).load(function () {
    $("#markerForm").submit(submit);
  });
```

Please let me know what the problem is. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By assigning the `submit` type to your button, your form is submitted before the Firebase `push()` method is triggered.

Changing the type to `button` and attaching a `click` event to this button, as follows, should do the trick:

### HTML

```
<form id="markerForm" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
    //...     
    <center><button id="formbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit">SUBMIT</button></center>
      </div>
</form>
```

### JS (index.js)

var config = {
      // my config details
    };

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var ref = firebase.database().ref("markers");

  var submit = function () {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var address = $("#address").val();
    var subject = $("#subject").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    ref.push({
      "name": name,
      "email": email,
      "address": address,
      "subject": subject,
      "message": message
    })
    .then(function(ref) {
      console.log(ref.parent + "/" + ref.key);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    })

  };

  $("#formbutton").click(function() {
    submit();
  });
```

See the [W3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) for more detail on the button types.

---

Also do not forget to wrap your `jquery` code in `$( document ).ready()`, see https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Note that there was a typo in my answer (`.submit();` instead of `submit();`). Please see the update

Comment: Yes i saw that and removed the ., it still doesnt work

Comment: No error, it just doesnt show up in Firebase @Renaud

Comment: See the update, with `then()` and `catch()`. Can you tell me what is the output of these `console.log()`??

Comment: index.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209885/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-satya-vejus).